# Function variable is not recognize in subquery

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

I want to write a function that counts non null and non empty entries of a field. My problem is that the query does not run since the @tableName variable is not recognized in the select statement and I do not know why

```
create function dbo.getCount(@cod int, @columnName as varchar(20), @tableName as varchar(20))
Returns int as 
Begin

--Count all filled entries
Return (select COUNT(*) from @tableName
where @columnName <> '' and @columnName is not null)

End;
go
```

Comment: if I cannot use a function for what I try to accomplish, what do you recommend? A stored procedure?

Comment: *"A stored procedure?"* yes, I'm writting an answer at the moment.

Comment: Aside: How would you ever write working code if the computer could decide on a whim whether a variable contained a value or something that looked a _little_ like code that might be worth executing? `declare @Value as VarChar(10) = '2 x pi'; if ( 6.28 = @Value ) ...`? `select * from @Name where @Name not like 'sys.%' and @ColumnName > @ColumnValue order by @StuffThatMightHaveColumnNamesOrNumbersWithDirections;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, but to reiterate, as I'll delete them after this answer:

> You can't do this with a function, for multiple reasons. `SELECT
>   COUNT(*) FROM @TableName` means count the number of rows in the
>   **table variable** `@TableName` *not* the table who's name is the *value* of `@TableName`. `WHERE @ColumnName <> ''` would mean where the value of the **scalar variable** doesn't have the value `''`,
>   *not* where the column (in the aforementioned table) with the name of value of `@ColumnName` doesn't have the value `''`.
>
> And you can't do this in a function as to do this type of thing, you
>   need dynamic SQL; and you can't use dynamic SQL in a function (as you
>   can't use the `EXEC` command).

You *can*, however, do this with a Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.GetCount @SchemaName sysname = N'dbo', @TableName sysname, @ColumnName sysname, @Count int OUTPUT AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

    SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT @Count = COUNT(NULLIF(' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N',''''))' + @CRLF +
                  N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N';'
    FROM sys.schemas s
         JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
         JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE s.[name] = @SchemaName
      AND t.[name] = @TableName
      AND c.[name] = @ColumnName;
    --PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging friend

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Count int OUTPUT', @Count OUTPUT;

END
GO
```

And you run the SP like below (with sample table):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (SomeColumn varchar(10));
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (SomeColumn)
VALUES(''),('abc'),(NULL);
GO


DECLARE @Count int;
EXEC dbo.GetCount @TableName = N'TestTable', @ColumnName = N'SomeColumn', @Count = @Count OUTPUT;

SELECT @Count; --Returns 1
GO
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d23ddf83ea972d40b3e7f772a7ac8c78)